# loading a texture in Opengl

Tags: opengl, c++

I am working on a graphics project I want to make a city using opengl with c++ anyway in the last few days I have been trying to load a texture but it didn't work with me in any way I have tried many codes and tried to follow some tutorials but it didn't went ok

here is my load texture function:

```
int LoadTexture(char *filename,int alpha) 
{
    int i, j=0; //Index variables
    FILE *l_file; //File pointer
    unsigned char *l_texture; //The pointer to the memory zone in which we will load the texture

    // windows.h gives us these types to work with the Bitmap files
    BITMAPFILEHEADER fileheader; 
    BITMAPINFOHEADER infoheader;
    RGBTRIPLE rgb;

    num_texture++; // The counter of the current texture is increased

    if( (l_file = fopen(filename, "rb"))==NULL) return (-1); // Open the file for reading

    fread(&fileheader, sizeof(fileheader), 1, l_file); // Read the fileheader

    fseek(l_file, sizeof(fileheader), SEEK_SET); // Jump the fileheader
    fread(&infoheader, sizeof(infoheader), 1, l_file); // and read the infoheader

    // Now we need to allocate the memory for our image (width * height * color deep)
    l_texture = (byte *) malloc(infoheader.biWidth * infoheader.biHeight * 4);
    // And fill it with zeros
    memset(l_texture, 0, infoheader.biWidth * infoheader.biHeight * 4);

    // At this point we can read every pixel of the image
    for (i=0; i < infoheader.biWidth*infoheader.biHeight; i++)
    {            
            // We load an RGB value from the file
            fread(&rgb, sizeof(rgb), 1, l_file); 

            // And store it
            l_texture[j+0] = rgb.rgbtRed; // Red component
            l_texture[j+1] = rgb.rgbtGreen; // Green component
            l_texture[j+2] = rgb.rgbtBlue; // Blue component
            l_texture[j+3] = alpha; // Alpha value
            j += 4; // Go to the next position
    }

    fclose(l_file); // Closes the file stream

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, num_texture); // Bind the ID texture specified by the 2nd parameter

    // The next commands sets the texture parameters
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT); // If the u,v coordinates overflow the range 0,1 the image is repeated
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR); // The magnification function ("linear" produces better results)
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR); //The minifying function

    glTexEnvf(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_DECR );

    // Finally we define the 2d texture
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 4, infoheader.biWidth, infoheader.biHeight, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, l_texture);

    // And create 2d mipmaps for the minifying function
    gluBuild2DMipmaps(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 4, infoheader.biWidth, infoheader.biHeight, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, l_texture);

    free(l_texture); // Free the memory we used to load the texture

    return (num_texture); // Returns the current texture OpenGL ID
}
```

I call the function in init section

```
textureID = LoadTexture("Building.bmp",255);
```

and in the display section I wrote :

```
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,textureID);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);  
            //front
            glTexCoord2f(1,0) ;         glVertex3f(1,-1,0); 
            glTexCoord2f(1,1) ;         glVertex3f(1,1,0);
            glTexCoord2f(0,1) ;         glVertex3f(-1,1,0);
            glTexCoord2f(0,0) ;         glVertex3f(-1,-1,0);
    glEnd();
```

Comment: Are you calling glGenTextures before glBindTexture?

Comment: @survivalMachine no I didn't call glGenTexture

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With open gl you can't just bind a texture before creating it.

Instead of keeping a counter called `num_textures`. **Each time you want to create a new texture**, retrieve a handle from OpenGL's `glGenTextures` function.

```
int id;
glGenTextures(1, &id);
```

So you would get rid of `num_texture` and all its usages.

And instead of this:

```
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, num_texture); // Bind the ID texture specified by the 2nd parameter
```

You write this:

```
int id;
glGenTextures(1, &id);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, id);
```

In other words you must use a handle OpenGL provides you, not just some random number you have decided.

In the future investigate using the `glGetError` function to see what went wrong as attempting to bind a texture that doesn't exist should give you a nice juicy error message.

Comment: you mean that I have to put this function in the initialize section ? and then use the id in loadtexture function ?

Comment: No sorry, I probably wasn't very clear. I've updated the answer now.